# Syntax for Apps Script 'File' Class and '.setContent' method using Drive Service

Tags: file, class, methods, google-apps-script

I'm trying to use the Google Apps Script `.setContent` method of the `File` Class.  I tried creating an object, then use the `.setContent` method on the object, but I'm getting an error:

***Cannot find function setContent in object FileIterator***

I'm trying to create the `File` object first with this line of code:

```
var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName('D12_20517_957');
```

Then put new content into the file:

```
files.setContent("This is the new content.");
```

What am I doing wrong?  Is the object valid?  The `.setContent` method obviously needs to know what the target is.

The `getFilesByName` method is a FileIterator collection.  Maybe I'm not actually creating a `File` object in the first place?  Okay, it seems that the `FileIterator` only has three methods, none of which has anything to do with setting the content.  But the example in the [Developers Class File Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file?hl=es) for `Class File` uses `getFilesByName`.

```
 // Trash every untitled spreadsheet that hasn't been updated in a week. 
 var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName('Untitled spreadsheet');
 while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();
   if (new Date() - file.getLastUpdated() > 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) {
     file.setTrashed(true);
   }
 }
```

And `setTrashed` is a method listed.  Maybe I need to use a `while` loop, even though I'm only trying to access one file?

So, I just tried using this:

```
function testWrite() {
   var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName('D12_20517_957');

   while (files.hasNext()) {
     var file = files.next();
       files.setContent("dbID");
   }
 };
```

I'm getting the same error.  I don't know what else to try.  How can I write new content to a Google document that is already created?

Comment: I actually got it to work!  I had a letter `s` on the end of `file` before `setContent`.  So I guess I can't work with just one file without iterating a `while` loop?  And I can't access just one file unless I know that file ID?  How do I get the file ID?  Maybe get the file ID at the point when the file is created?

Comment: I just noticed that there is a `DocsList` service that can create files.  Maybe I'd be better off using that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setContent(content)`

> Overwrites the content of the file with a given replacement

`setContent` is a `Method`, so it invokes an action.  It replaces all the content in whatever is being referenced.  **NOTE**:  `setContent()` is a method used in multiple Classes.  E.g. Drive, Comment

I wanted to reference a single file ***by name***, and that *is* possible, but as of the moment I'm writing this, it's not a one step process.

There are various ways to reference a file:

1. var files = DriveApp.getFiles(); Gets a ***COLLECTION*** of ***FILES***.
2. var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(name);  Gets a ***COLLECTION*** of ***FILES***.
3. var files = DriveApp.getFileById(id);  Gets a ***SINGLE*** file.

In Google Drive there can be multiple files all with the same name.  This is why you can't get a single file ***BY NAME*** in ***One Step***.

You *can* get a single file by name, but even though it's just a single file, you **must** use a `File Iterator` over a ***COLLECTION*** of files, even though the `getFilesByName(name)` method may only return one file.  So, . . . . now I understand what's going on.  This is what they don't explain to you in the documentation.